# Using Python, how can I tell the user they already entered a number in the list?

Tags: python

I have to write a program for my class that

- gets user input (numbers)
- make to parallel list for even numbers and odd numbers
- tell the user is a number was already entered
- print the list
- and other things I know how to do.

I have everything else just the only thing I don't know how to do is tell the user that a number was already entered.

My teacher said to try a for loop but I can't figure it out.

Comment: If it's homework you should tag it "homework". And please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the following example code and try to adapt its ideas. the "in" keyword is python specific and replaces iterating over the lists while comparing.

```
odd = [1, 3, 5, 7]
even = [2, 4, 6, 8]

user_input = int(raw_input("enter a number: "))

if user_input in odd or user_input in even:
  print "the number "+str(user_input)+" was already entered"
else:
  if user_input %2 == 0:
    even.append(user_input)
    print "added to even list"
  else:
    odd.append(user_input)
    print "added to odd list"
```

here is an example of how to use a for loop:

```
some_list = [1,2,6,7]

is_in_the_list = False
for x in some_list:
  if x == 7: # 7 plays the role of the user input here
    is_in_the_list = True

if is_in_the_list:
  print "It is in the list"
```

Answer (score 2):

Start reading about testing membership with [in](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in) and  using [set](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) to create unique list of numbers